# Problem with XML serialisation and C#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialise some C# classes to XML. Things were going fine until I tried to introduce some inherited classes.

The classes are [edited for size]

```
public class ParticipationClass
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string typeCode;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string contextControlCode;

    public ParticipationClass()
    {
    }
}


public class p_recordTarget : ParticipationClass
{
    public p_recordTarget()
    {
        typeCode = "RCT";
        contextControlCode = "OP";
    }
}
```

when using the classes the following code is used :

```
public class Test
{

    // other class attributes excluded.. 

    [XmlElement]
    public ParticipationClass recordTarget;

    private void Test()
    {
        recordTarget = new p_recordTarget();
    }
}
```

The serialisation fails with an InvalidOperationException, looking in the exception detail I can see "Message="The type itk.cda.cdaclasses.p_recordTarget was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."

So I guess I need an XmlInclude, but I am not sure how.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, you need to use the attribute on the base class to let the serializer know about the derived classes:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(p_recordTarget))]
public class ParticipationClass {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have tried this and it does not seem to make any difference. Looking at Simon's answer (which is the same) and other web resources I suspect this should be the answer. But it still does not work, and yields the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you out:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/xmlserializerforunknown.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(p_recordTarget))]
public class ParticipationClass
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string typeCode;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string contextControlCode;

    public ParticipationClass()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Simon, see the comments I made to Jon ( who had the same answer ). I think it should work but it does not appear to.

Comment: I think you can also put it on the method, but I should have the same effet. Or It's a cache issue. Serialization is cached (whenever possible).